# Merge/Join Data Frame / Table based on criteria - > or <

Tags: r, merge, dataframe, data.table

I have a data frame with weekly data by Section.  Each Section has approx 104 weeks worth of data and there is 83 sections in total.

I have a second data frame with the Start and End week by Section that I want to filter the main data frame on.

In both tables the Week is a combination of Year and Week e.g. 201501 and is always from weeks 1 to 52.

So in the example below I want to filter Section A by weeks 201401 to 201404, Section B by weeks 201551 to 201603.

I initially thought I could add an additional column to my Weeks_Filter data frame that is a sequential number from the start and end of the the weeks for each section (duplicating each row for each week), then merge the 2 tables and keep all the data from the Weeks_Filter table (all.y = TRUE) because this worked on a small sample I did but I don't know how to add the sequential weeks since they can span different years.

```
Week <- c("201401","201402","201403","201404","201405", "201451", "201552", "201601", "201602", "201603")
Section <- c(rep("A",5),rep("B",5))
df <- data.frame(cbind(Week, Section))

Section <- c("A", "B")
Start <- c("201401","201551")
End <- c("201404","201603")
Weeks_Filter <- data.frame(cbind(Section, Start, End))
```

Answer (score -2, accepted):

```
require(data.table)

df <- merge(df, Weeks_Filter)
df[, -1] <- apply(df[, -1], 2, function(x) as.numeric(as.character(x)))
df <- data.table(df)

df[Week >= Start & Week <= End, .SD, by = Section]
```

The Output is,

```
   Section  Start    End   Week
1:       A 201401 201404 201401
2:       A 201401 201404 201402
3:       A 201401 201404 201403
4:       A 201401 201404 201404
5:       B 201551 201603 201552
6:       B 201551 201603 201601
7:       B 201551 201603 201602
8:       B 201551 201603 201603
```

Comment: I am wondering, why the answer is getting down vote. Does people like complex solution rather than simpler one.

Comment: the answer worked fine for me. I am new to R and despite using the link provided below I was not able to get the answer to work.

Answer (score 4):

The latest [development version](https://github.com/Rdatatable/data.table/wiki/Installation) of `data.table` adds non-equi joins (and in the older ones you can use `foverlaps`):

```
setDT(df) # convert to data.table in place
setDT(Weeks_Filter)

# fix the column types - you have factors currently, converting to integer
df[, Week := as.integer(as.character(Week))]
Weeks_Filter[, `:=`(Start = as.integer(as.character(Start)),
                    End   = as.integer(as.character(End)))]

# the actual magic
df[df[Weeks_Filter, on = .(Section, Week >= Start, Week <= End), which = T]]
#     Week Section
#1: 201401       A
#2: 201402       A
#3: 201403       A
#4: 201404       A
#5: 201552       B
#6: 201601       B
#7: 201602       B
#8: 201603       B
```

Comment: we can also use `x.` prefix now.. (particularly useful to refer to x's join columns) `df[Weeks_Filter, .(x.Week, Section), on = .(Section, Week >= Start, Week <= End)]`

Comment: @eddi thanks for the reply. I was unable to replicate your answer and I think this is because I don't have the same version of data.table.  The error I had was:  could not find function "."

Comment: Use the link in the answer to get the latest version.

Answer (score 1):

Using `dplyr` you can

- combine your data frames
- group by Section
- filter based on the Start and End columns

One problem is that your 'weeks' are characters and become factors the way you've encoded them. I took the shortcut and just made them numeric, but I'd recommend using `lubridate` to make these proper Date class vectors.

```
library(dplyr)
tempdf <- full_join(df, Weeks_Filter)
tempdf$Week <- as.numeric(as.character(tempdf$Week))
tempdf$Start <- as.numeric(as.character(tempdf$Start))
tempdf$End <- as.numeric(as.character(tempdf$End))


tempdf_filt <- tempdf %>%
  group_by(Section) %>%
  filter(Week >= Start,
         Week <= End)
```

It looks like there's a problem in your data that "201451" should be "201551", but otherwise returns what you want:

```
> tempdf_filt
Source: local data frame [8 x 4]
Groups: Section [2]

    Week Section  Start    End
   (dbl)  (fctr)  (dbl)  (dbl)
1 201401       A 201401 201404
2 201402       A 201401 201404
3 201403       A 201401 201404
4 201404       A 201401 201404
5 201552       B 201551 201603
6 201601       B 201551 201603
7 201602       B 201551 201603
8 201603       B 201551 201603
```

Comment: a year has 52 weeks ;)

Comment: @ johnSG Thank you - I did have a typo in there.  I am trying to master data.table so I've used that but this also worked well.

Comment: @eddi I had a typo in pointing out the typo (karma). 201501 --> 201551. fixed now

Comment: @MidnightDataGeek, if you're trying to master data.table, do NOT accept / follow that answer from TheRimalaya.

Comment: @Arun I am new to R, can you elaborate further on why I shouldn't accept it? Thanks.

Comment: @MidnightDataGeek, because it is a bad answer. There's nothing being done with *data.table*. It uses base R (nothing wrong with that, although using `apply()` on a data.frame isn't particularly efficient as it coerces the data.frame to a matrix) for the most part, and then simply converts (unnecessarily copying) to data.table and the only thing it does after that is to subset. It is poor and bad code (for using data.tables).

Comment: @Arun I am more than happy to use your suggestion if you are willing to provide an answer.
In the end I just mapped in the From and To weeks and then used the following: 
    `data[Week_Filter >= From & Week_Filter <= To, .SD, by = Section]`

This has filtered out all the rows I don't need and has left me with 52 observations for each Section.

Answer (score 0):

Perhaps creating a vector of all desired weeks would work for the filter. Here is a rough example using base R:

```
# get weeks
allWeeks <- as.character(1:52)
allWeeks <- ifelse(nchar(allWeeks)==1, paste0("0",allWeeks), allWeeks)
# get all year-weeks
allWeeks <- paste0(2014:2015, allWeeks)

# filter vector to select desired weeks
keepWeeks <- keepWeeks[grep("201(40[1-4]|55[12]|60[123]))", allWeeks)]

dfKeeper <- df[df$Week %in% keepWeeks,]
```

I tried to construct a regular expression that would capture the periods that you want, but you may have to adjust it a bit.